# Error is coming in Arraylist 's list.add()

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using Eclipse JUno ,I am having trouble with the .add() of the arraylist guys please help.here is my code

```
     import java.util.ArrayList;
public class A
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
    list.add(90);
    list.add(9.9);
    list.add("abc");
    list.add(true);
    System.out.println(list);
  }
}
```

the error which is coming is :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method add(int, Object) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (int)
    The method add(Object) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (double)
    The method add(Object) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)

    at A.main(A.java:7)
```

but here is the weird thing ,that  the line

```
  list.add("abc");
```

is not causing any error.. ADD method of list take  one argument which is an object type then why i am facing this problem please help guys..i had searched a lot  i did not get any solution.I have to do practice on this and due to this error i cant continue my practice..

Comment: What version of java do you use?

Comment: Your code works fine: http://ideone.com/4ONRdV - Update to the latest Java version.

Comment: i know this is dumb Q but i am using jdk 1.7 right now and how to update it..last time i run this cade was 6 month ago and i think it was on jdk 1.5 or maybe 1.6 it was working fine there then why it is not working in jdk 1.7...did they change something during updation ,if this so then it is really noob thing to do

Comment: @user2461414 did you try to compile your code from command line?

Comment: @user2461414 and `javac -version` gives your 1.7?

Comment: @user2461414 just for fun. Try `javac -source 1.7 A.java` :)

Comment: javac -version give me 1.8

Comment: @user2461414 о_О you're using openjdk 1.8 that in development now?

Comment: yup i am using that from past 1 month ,did u dont know about that

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that you're using java prior version 1.5. [Autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) was introduced in java 1.5. And your code compiles fine on java 1.5+.

Compile as source 1.4:

```
javac -source 1.4 A.java


A.java:7: error: no suitable method found for add(int)
    list.add(90);
        ^
    method ArrayList.add(int,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ArrayList.add(Object) is not applicable
      (actual argument int cannot be converted to Object by method invocation conversion)
A.java:8: error: no suitable method found for add(double)
    list.add(9.9);
        ^
    method ArrayList.add(int,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ArrayList.add(Object) is not applicable
      (actual argument double cannot be converted to Object by method invocation conversion)
A.java:10: error: no suitable method found for add(boolean)
    list.add(true);
        ^
    method ArrayList.add(int,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ArrayList.add(Object) is not applicable
      (actual argument boolean cannot be converted to Object by method invocation conversion)
3 errors
```

With 1.5 (or later):

```
javac -source 1.5 A.java

warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
Note: A.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning
```

I **suggest you to update your java** or box all primitives to objects manually, as @SoulDZIN suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the 'add' method is failing for the data types:

int, double, and boolean.

These are all primitive data types and not 'Objects', which the method is expecting. I believe that autoboxing is not occurring here because you are using literal values, I'm not sure about this though. Nevertheless, to fix this, use the associated Object type of each primitive:

```
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
list.add(new Integer(90));
list.add(new Double(9.9));
list.add("abc");
list.add(new Boolean(true));
System.out.println(list);
```

SOURCE: Experience

EDIT:

I always try to specify the type of my Collection, even if it is an Object.

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

However, apparently this isn't a good practice if you are running Java 1.4 or less.

Comment: No! Remove generics! If it is Java 1.4, so generics aren't available. Your question was right without generics update!

Comment: @Andremoniy Better? I'm not too familiar with the earlier versions of Java.

Answer (score 0):

**Works great with JDK 6**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
            list.add(90);
            list.add(9.9);
            list.add("abc");
            list.add(true);
            System.out.println(list);
    }
```

**Printed result** :[90, 9.9, abc, true].

If still you are using lesser version than **jdk 6**.Please specify version.